# redirecting subdomain to main domain with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I am building a website with two main sections,

so I have created two subdomains:

web1.example.com
web2.example.com

since i'm building websites with codeigniter, I want to redirect to the index.php page. here's what I did:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web1.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/web1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

it works as expected, but it changes the url to example.com/web1..
is there any way to keep the url web1.example.com, but still redirecting to example.com/web1?

I already am using .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

when I enter web1.example.com, the actual url to be executed should be:
example.com/web1, and file to be executed is index.php ..

Comment: What is your expected output URL

Answer (score 1):

Didnt tested, Modify and try this

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).example.com$ http://example.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+).example.com/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+) http://example.com/$1&$2 [L]
```

**Edited 1**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/index.php/%1&$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: What is your expected output URL and What URL need to be executed

Comment: should I place .htaccess inside sub domain folder, or in root directory?

Comment: edited my question with current htaccess file..
tried to add your code to it, but nothing happens..

Comment: Also provide: example url, expected url, the file need to execute on that url

Comment: when I enter web1.example.com, the actual url to be executed should be: example.com/web1, and file to be executed is index.php ..

this is what you meant?

Comment: Yes, wats the parameter that pass to index.php

Comment: there could be countless number of parameters, URI segments..
there is one required param which is 'web1' or 'web2', depends on which sub-domain you entered..

Comment: where is the index.php file

Comment: example.com?index.php&sub=web1  Is this to be executed for web1.example.com

Comment: see the Edited 1 above

Comment: works, but I am redirected to example.com/web1 instead of staying in web1.example.com ..